# Save contact form data in the database instead of transferring it to an email account

Tags: 8, emails

So far I had to set up email DNS records and an email server or, alternatively, an email proxy by an email account to transfer emails from a CMS to my email account.

1. Email DNS records and email server
   Contact form inquiry → PHP `mail()` function → Postfix → SMTP → My email account
2. Email proxy
   Contact form inquiry → PHP `mail()` function → Mail Transfer Agent (like `sSMTP`) → SMTP → Email proxy account → My email account

All I want to is to get leads (contact form inquiries) directly into Drupal in a secured way and to manage them from Drupal (in a rather simple way of *keep or delete*).

The advantages (mainly for freelance, single-administrator applications) are

1. Easier server and credentials management (No need to worry about securing credentials for an email proxy account.)
2. Fast email reply (by clicking on the email address of the inquirer from browser or from smartphone) and sending an email directly from your preferred email application in regular PC or smartphone

How could I "instruct" the core *Contact* module to save leads in Drupal itself and not transferring them to any email account? (I might need a third-party module for that, if it's not possible without customizing its PHP code.)

Comment: IMO Contact module has never been that useful. Use Webform.

Comment: [Webform is available for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/releases/8.x-5.1), and it has been for a while already. We have plenty of Drupal 8 sites using it.

Comment: Webform has been around a while....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is the purpose of the [Contact Storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) module.

If you need further form elements, consider using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module. It surely adds a whole lot of overhead, but gives you a wide variety of form elements and stores it's results in the database as well.